# iTextPdf7 - Get font from resources

Tags: java, custom-font, itext7

I am using iText7 to create PDF's with Java. I use some custom fonts, and those files are on the `resources` folder.

While I am testing and running the app on netbeans, this works perfectly:

```
PdfFontFactory.register("./src/main/resources/GOTHAM-BOLD.otf", "gotham-bold");
PdfFont gBold = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("gotham-bold", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
```

But when I build, and try running the app and generating the PDF file, iText can't find the font files, because it needs the direct `path` to it. 
What alternatives do I have? I really need to this in order to work in any pc (like the other resources).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure why you are using aliases. You can use other factory methods that accept `byte[]` arrays in combination with `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` to retrieve the contents of the font resource which can be used to create a `FontProgram` instance and then construct a `PdfFont`.

You code can be changed as follows:

```
// Apache Commons IO is used, but any way of retrieving bytes from stream will suffice
byte[] fontContents = IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("GOTHAM-BOLD.otf"));

FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(fontContents);
document.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H));
```

If you work in a static context, you can use it like `Main.class.getResourceAsStream()` (put your class name instead of `Main`).

Make sure the font resource appears in the final assembly and you are good to go. There is no dependency on any URLs in this approach.

Comment: this worked only for when running on NetBeans... But when running the builded one it still could not load the font. It gives a `null pointer exception` . I confirmed and the fonts are in the jar including all the other resources (Also, I can visualise them while "workin" - the problem is when generating PDF file)

Comment: @Anonirato  that is implausible unless the jar is incorrectly built. Alexey simply proposed the standard approach for the task at hand.

Comment: @Alexey I had some other problems not related to this question! Yourr answer worked perfectly! Thank you!